How to bypass the login page (MohmmedAshraf/laravel-translations package)?
Github (package)
This package has an authorization page, how to make sure that the main condition is whether the user is authorized in the filament admin panel or not.
That is, /translations page opens, if the user is not authorized in filament, he should be redirected to filament.auth.login, otherwise do not ask for a login and password and give the opportunity to change\add translations.
How to rewrite logic if it is “inside the package” / vendor folder

